# What is the best approach to open a TXT file from assets and read a string?

Tags: android, inputstream, assets

I need to check if a txt file exists on assets folder, and if exists I need to read the text of it and put into a string.

I saw some approaches on Google to open files from assets but I can't find one that gives you the possibility to check if the file exists and then read a string from it (because is a text resource).

Comment: Assets are bundled into the apk, how could the file not exist?  Am I missing something?

Comment: Files can not exists because these apps are autogenerated with an app generator, and can not contain a file sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just handle the exception properly when the file isn't found like this :

```
try {

    InputStream is = SplashscreenActivity.this.getAssets().open("yourTextFile.txt");

} catch (IOException e) {
    // catch your exception properly when the file isn't found
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In short, you must already suppose to know if the file exists in **assets** or not. Because assets folder is packed up with files once you build your .apk file and can never be changed.

So, its pretty lame to verify if the file exists or not. It will only contain those files which you have added yourself.

More over, if you want to use `R` file to help you locate the file name, then simply put your files in a folder called **raw**. Its an alternate to **assets** but the files saved in this folder are referenced in the `R` class file - making it easier to get hold of the resource.

Comment: Files can not exists because these apps are autogenerated with an app generator, and can not contain a file sometimes. This answer must be deleted

Comment: **"these apps are autogenerated with an app generator"** what does that suppose to mean?

Comment: i'm programming an app generator that will receive asset's folder's created by other users. Please, stop this and delete this answer

Comment: First, you need to revise your concepts on assets and then think if it really needs to be downvoted. Read it yourself http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html